# MSB3103 Invalid Resx file. Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to build a project and receive following error:

Error   MSB3103 Invalid Resx file. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\User.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.1\ref\net45\System.Buffers.dll' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) Line 30, position 1856.  Proj    C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Source Code\Forms\FormTimer.resx 30

What could be the solution for this error? It´s being shown in multiple resxes

I´m lost and I can´t seem to figure this out.

I use Visual Studio Community edition 2022.

Comment: How System.Buffers got used for a resource in a .resx file is very hard to guess.  You'll have to show us.